# Firebase detach only one of the listeners on the same path

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 firebase listeners on the same path. One of them fetches most recent items and the other one is query-like which gives specific user items. Both are fired on value. Is it possible to detach one of these listeners while keeping the other?

```
postRef = db.ref(`posts/${location}`)
postRef.orderByChild('timestamp').limitToLast(10).on("value", 
    function(snapshot) {
        dispatch({
        type: "POST_GET_POST",
        payload: snapshot.val()
    })
})

userRef = db.ref(`posts/`)
userRef.child(location).orderByChild("user").equalTo(user.uid).on("value", 
    function(snapshot) {
        dispatch({
          type: "POST_USER_POST",
          payload: snapshot.val()
    })
})
```

Below code will just turn both of the above listeners off.

```
ref = db.ref(`posts/${location}`)
ref.off
```

I've considered changing one of these listeners to be on child_added so I can pass the event type to ref.off() in order to select that listener. However this approach feels like going around the problem so I've wanted to know if this is possible to do in any other way.

Comment: I don't understand - [off()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#off) takes three arguments, but in your code, you're not even invoking it as a function with parenthesis.

Comment: that was just supposed to be a pseudo code but what i was using is ref.off() anyways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you register a listener, `on()` returns a reference to that precise listener. If you pass that reference into `off()` only that listener will be removed.

So:

```
var query = postRef.orderByChild('timestamp').limitToLast(10);
var listener = query.on("value", 
  ...
```

And then:

```
query.off(listener);
```

Comment: Would it make sense to keep all listener references within the application state in order to pass them to destruction or switch functions?

Comment: That depends on where you register the listeners. I find it most convenient to put `on()` and `off()` in complementary lifecycle events, and then keep the listener reference in the containing component/class.

Comment: By the way do i need to declare both query and listener as you did above and store them or is there a way to have a one line call and a single reference?